# Attribute error when using Popen

Tags: python-3.x, popen, raspberry-pi2, face-recognition

Hello I'm coming with up an error when I'm using popen with my facial recognition software, in Python version 3.

What I'm aiming to do is for the code to take a photo of the person's face and if the person is in the 'known' folder of people then it turns on the green LED, if the person doesn't match any of the faces in the 'known' folder then it turns on the red LED. This is the code I'm using.

```
import os
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import sys
import subprocess

os.system('raspistill -o image.jpg -w 1280 -h 1024')
x = os.system('cp image.jpg /home/pi/face_recognition/face_recognition/unknown/unknown.jpg')
print(x)

process = subprocess.Popen('python3 cli.py known unknown | cut -d "," -f2', shell=True)
process.wait()
output = process.check_output()
print(output)

if output == b'unknown_person\n':
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.OUT)
    print("Red LED on")
    GPIO.output(18,GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(3)
    print("Red LED off")
    GPIO.output(18,GPIO.LOW)
else:
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    GPIO.setup(17,GPIO.OUT)
    print("Green LED on")
    GPIO.output(17,GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(3)
    print("Green LED off")
    GPIO.output(17,GPIO.LOW)
```

The command that we took from the command prompt runs the following code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function
import click
import os
import re
import scipy.misc
import warnings
import face_recognition.api as face_recognition
import multiprocessing
import itertools
import sys


def scan_known_people(known_people_folder):
    known_names = []
    known_face_encodings = []

    for file in image_files_in_folder(known_people_folder):
        basename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file))[0]
        img = face_recognition.load_image_file(file)
        encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(img)

        if len(encodings) > 1:
            click.echo("WARNING: More than one face found in {}. Only considering the first face.".format(file))

        if len(encodings) == 0:
            click.echo("WARNING: No faces found in {}. Ignoring file.".format(file))
        else:
            known_names.append(basename)
            known_face_encodings.append(encodings[0])

    return known_names, known_face_encodings


def print_result(filename, name, distance, show_distance=False):
    if show_distance:
        print("{},{},{}".format(filename, name, distance))
    else:
        print("{},{}".format(filename, name))


def test_image(image_to_check, known_names, known_face_encodings, tolerance=0.6, show_distance=False):
    unknown_image = face_recognition.load_image_file(image_to_check)

    # Scale down image if it's giant so things run a little faster
    if unknown_image.shape[1] > 1600:
        scale_factor = 1600.0 / unknown_image.shape[1]
        with warnings.catch_warnings():
            warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
            unknown_image = scipy.misc.imresize(unknown_image, scale_factor)

    unknown_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(unknown_image)

    for unknown_encoding in unknown_encodings:
        distances = face_recognition.face_distance(known_face_encodings, unknown_encoding)
        result = list(distances <= tolerance)

        if True in result:
            [print_result(image_to_check, name, distance, show_distance) for is_match, name, distance in zip(result, known_names, distances) if is_match]
        else:
            print_result(image_to_check, "unknown_person", None, show_distance)


def image_files_in_folder(folder):
    return [os.path.join(folder, f) for f in os.listdir(folder) if re.match(r'.*\.(jpg|jpeg|png)', f, flags=re.I)]


def process_images_in_process_pool(images_to_check, known_names, known_face_encodings, number_of_cpus, tolerance, show_distance):
    if number_of_cpus == -1:
        processes = None
    else:
        processes = number_of_cpus

    # macOS will crash due to a bug in libdispatch if you don't use 'forkserver'
    context = multiprocessing
    if "forkserver" in multiprocessing.get_all_start_methods():
        context = multiprocessing.get_context("forkserver")

    pool = context.Pool(processes=processes)

    function_parameters = zip(
        images_to_check,
        itertools.repeat(known_names),
        itertools.repeat(known_face_encodings),
        itertools.repeat(tolerance),
        itertools.repeat(show_distance)
    )

    pool.starmap(test_image, function_parameters)


@click.command()
@click.argument('known_people_folder')
@click.argument('image_to_check')
@click.option('--cpus', default=1, help='number of CPU cores to use in parallel (can speed up processing lots of images). -1 means "use all in system"')
@click.option('--tolerance', default=0.6, help='Tolerance for face comparisons. Default is 0.6. Lower this if you get multiple matches for the same person.')
@click.option('--show-distance', default=False, type=bool, help='Output face distance. Useful for tweaking tolerance setting.')
def main(known_people_folder, image_to_check, cpus, tolerance, show_distance):
    known_names, known_face_encodings = scan_known_people(known_people_folder)

    # Multi-core processing only supported on Python 3.4 or greater
    if (sys.version_info < (3, 4)) and cpus != 1:
        click.echo("WARNING: Multi-processing support requires Python 3.4 or greater. Falling back to single-threaded processing!")
        cpus = 1

    if os.path.isdir(image_to_check):
        if cpus == 1:
            [test_image(image_file, known_names, known_face_encodings, tolerance, show_distance) for image_file in image_files_in_folder(image_to_check)]
        else:
            process_images_in_process_pool(image_files_in_folder(image_to_check), known_names, known_face_encodings, cpus, tolerance, show_distance)
    else:
        test_image(image_to_check, known_names, known_face_encodings, tolerance, show_distance)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    enter code here
```

The error that comes up from this is as follows.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/DataFace code.py", line 13, in <module>
    output = process.check_output()
AttributeError: 'Popen' object has no attribute 'check_output'
```

If I could as quick of a response as quick as possible that would be greatly appreciated ^_^